# What is a good way to handle a couple of web.config files that have the same structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a multi tenant application that has already 6 tenants.

Each tenant has its own virtual web with its own web.config. Most of the setting are the same for all tenants, but some differ.

Its getting more and more difficult to handle those settings. The first step to simplify the situation would be if I could edit settings that are shared by all tenants in one place.

Is there something built into the framework or some project that targets this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, web.config is hierarchical. i.e if you have a directory with web.config and lower level directories with their own web.config and when you navigate between those directories, the settings within web.config are overlaid.. That said, I have forgotten the rules of engagement for such a setting.

A simple, more more manageable solution might be to have your own sections that you can plug into web.config and have your own XML config file that you can can reference from web.config. Its simple enough to build and you can manage the way your hierarchies work.

Comment: Some good links: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032807-1.aspx , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155/how-do-i-define-custom-web-config-sections-with-potential-child-elements-and-attr HTH