# How to open a config file app settings using ConfigurationManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, configurationmanager

My config file is located here:

```
"~/Admin/Web.config"
```

I tried opening it via the below code but it didn't work:

```
var physicalFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Admin/Web.config");
var configMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(physicalFilePath);
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(configMap);
var appSettingsSection = (AppSettingsSection)configuration.GetSection("appSettings");
```

when appsettings line runs, it throws the below error message:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to type 'System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection'.
```

My Web.Config looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AdminUsername" value="Test1"/>
    <add key="AdminPassword" value="Test2"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

How could I get the appsettings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For web-app, you need to use [`System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) class and no need to set absolute path.

```
var web=System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager
          .OpenWebConfiguration("~/admin/web.config");

String appValue=web.AppSettings.Settings["key"].Value;
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when accessing its AppSettings property: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to type 'System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection'.

Comment: How to open .net core appsettings.json ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for adding some stuff to the Web.config, and then reading it from the code.
What you need is **Custom Configuration Sections in Web.config**

Look here:
[How do I define custom web.config sections with potential child elements and attributes for the properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155/how-do-i-define-custom-web-config-sections-with-potential-child-elements-and-att)
and here:
[Creating Custom Configuration Sections in Web.config - 4GuysFromRolla.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133931/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032807-1.aspx)